# How to use node_modules on a "traditional website"?

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have used node to manage dependencies on React apps and the like, in those you use package.json to keep track of libs and use them in your scripts using ES6 import module syntax.

But now I'm working on a legacy code base that uses a bunch of jQuery plugins (downloaded manually and placed in a "libs" folder) and links them directly in the markup using script tags.

I want to use npm to manage these dependencies. Is my only option:

- run npm init
- install all plugins through npm and have them in package.json
- link to the scripts in the node_modules folder directly from the markup:

  `<script src="./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>`

or is there a better way?

Comment: This was the entire premise of Grunt and Gulp and all the rest of the NodeJS task manager toolset. It is not recommended to expose the entire node_modules folder as a public resource on your web server. I recommend using a task manager, write a 'build' task that copies the JavaScript source files out of node_modules and into a folder containing static assets for your server.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Gotcha, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/modern-approach-of-javascript-bundling-with-webpack-3b7b3e5f4e7) for going from using script tags to bundling with Webpack. You will want to do the following: **(Do steps 1 and 2 as you mentioned in your question then your step 3 will change to the following 3 steps)**

1. Download webpack with npm: `npm install webpack --save-dev`
2. Create a `webpack.config.js` file specifying your entry file and output file. Your entry file will contain *any custom JS components your app is using.* You will also need to specify to include your node_modules within your generated Javascript bundle. Your *output file will be the resulting Javascript bundle* that Webpack will create for you and it will contain all the necessary Javascript your app needs to run. A simple example `webpack.config.js` would be the following:

   ```
   const path = require('path');
       module.exports = {
         entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
         output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
           filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
         },
         resolve: {
           alias: {
             'node_modules': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
           }
         }
       };
   ```
3. Lastly, add a `<script>` tag within your main HTML page pointing to your newly generated Javascript bundle:

   ```
   <script src="dist/my-first-webpack.bundle.js"></script>
   ```

Now your web application should work the same as before your refactoring journey.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Parcel js](https://parceljs.org/docs/).

Then you only need:

1. Run `npm init`
2. Install dependency, for example `npm install jquery`
3. Import with ES6 syntax: `import $ from "jquery";`

And run with parcel